# \Alignat and page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, alignat

I have noticed that `pdflatex` is very uneager to break pages within an `alignat` row of equations. It prefers rather to leave large pieces of pages blank than to break up the row of equations.

The figure attached below illustrates the issue pretty well, I hope:

[image]

Is there any way, I can make `pdflatex` more eager to create evenly filled pages?

Thank you in advance, 
Best Regards,
Lars

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: have you used `\allowdisplaybreaks`

Comment: Add `\displaybreak` before one of the ``\\`` marks in the alignment in the second page. You can also set `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble, but that should only be done in the preliminary stages; use your judgment to break the display. By the way, I can't see applications for `alignat` in those displays, which are simply `align`.

Comment: 'alignat' is used since "tabular" is needed both for equality signs and the descriptions under which conditions the equations are valid, for instance '\forall i', etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think `\allowdisplaybreaks`did solve my problem!